# fql - fbconnect getting first post ever

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect, facebook-fql

I want to get the first stream record ever. I tried:

```
SELECT post_id,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 610611346 ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 1
```

But it gives me the LATEST instead of the FIRST post :(. I increased the limit to 5 just to have a look at what it was bringing back and it is simply the last 5 posts in ascending order. I guess I'm confusing LIMIT with like an index. How can this be done?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you:

```
SELECT post_id,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 610611346 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 1
```